# IntelliJ Application testing on Android device

Tags: android, intellij-idea, development-environment, htc-android

Hy Everybody!

I am starting to learn android development and I would like to try my applications on my HTC (wildfire s) android device(smartphone). My big big problem is a can't do that.
The intellij provide the following after i am clicking a run button:

```
Waiting for device.  
Target device: SH1A3TR00615  
Uploading file  
    local path: D:\javas\MyActivity\out\production\MyActivity\MyActivity.apk  
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.MyActivity  
Installing com.example.MyActivity  
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.MyActivity"  
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.MyActivity  
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]
```

I am - using IntelliJ,
     - installed HTC Sync
     - installed Android SDK Tools(1.16)
     - installed ADBDriver

The way how I am creating and running my first app:
File->new project
In the popup window I choose - under android secion - Application Module
Project SDK: Android 4.4 Platform(java version 1.7.0_45)
At more settings Project format: .idea(directory based)
...and my project created, there is an AndroidMainfest.xml, the src folder, and some other file and folder too.

My AndroidMainfest.xml looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.MyActivity"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19"/>
    <application android:debuggable="true" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

*When I am click on the android icon at the bottom, it opens a window and I see a "running rows" when I am touching my phone, so I suppose the IntelliJ known about my phone.*
*I tried to exit and start Intellij again, but the probel was still there.*

*If I choose a target device at startup "Choose a running device", I see there my phone, but: Compatible: no*

Please somebody help me to get started android developing on my device....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error looks to me like you lack sufficient space on your internal memory. You might need to clean up some of the data internally before it will let you flash the apk onto the device. Alternately, you can take that apk which sits at the path listed, and by mounting your sd card, assuming you have an external microSD in your phone, place it there before installing manually from your phone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your  uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" to  uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" and set your compiler to 1.6 (you can find this under settings - compiler - Java Compiler - and then select 1.6 (a project bytecode version(right hand side)).

Hope this helps

Chow